# Using GnuPG; I enter one keyID for "edit key" command and then get a different key in the "edit" menu

Tags: command-line, gnupg, pgp

Please help me to understand what is happening.

On command line in Windows I learn that my key is 4096 and expires on 2020-07-31

```
C:\Users\Vivarto>gpg -K C2EBD198
sec   4096R/C2EBD198 2018-08-04 [expires: 2020-07-31]
uid                  vivarto (PrivacyEverywhere) <vivarto@gmail.com>
uid                  vivarto (PrivacyEverywhere) <veet_vivarto@yahoo.com>
uid                  vivarto (PrivacyEverywhere) <mistergod@yahoo.com>
uid                  vivarto (Privacy Everywhere) <vivarto@hotmail.com>
uid                  vivarto (Privacy Everywhere) <crocorocodile@gmail.com>
uid                  vivarto (Privacy Everywhere) <babbbayaggga@gmail.com>
uid                  vivarto (Privacy Everywhere) <vivarto@mail.ru>
uid                  vivarto (Privacy Everywhere) <vivarto@gmx.com>
uid                  vivarto (PrivacyEverywhere) <vivarto@mail.ru>
uid                  vivarto (PrivacyEverywhere) <vivarto@hotmail.com>
uid                  vivarto (Privacy Everywhere) <vivarto@outlook.co.il>
uid                  vivarto (PrivacyEverywhere) <babbbayaggga@gmail.com>
uid                  vivarto (PrivacyEverywhere) <crocorocodile@gmail.com>
uid                  vivarto (Privacy Everywhere) <privacyeverywhere@gmail.com>
ssb   4096R/C4CF0B22 2018-08-04 [expires: 2020-07-31]
```

The fingerprint for this key is

```
Key fingerprint = 80EB F59A AFC3 E2F5 0427  EF1E 229E 1A49 C2EB D198
```

Then when I run edit key command I get something entirely different

```
C:\Users\Vivarto>gpg --edit key  80EBF59AAFC3E2F50427EF1E229E1A49C2EBD198
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.23; Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.


pub  1024R/A12535C5  created: 2019-01-21  expired: 2019-01-22  usage: SC
                     trust: unknown       validity: expired
sub  1024R/63BC5E5E  created: 2019-01-21  expired: 2019-01-22  usage: E
[ expired] (1). Test_Key1024 (no comment) <Test@test.test>

No user ID with index 80
```

So I am not able to edit my key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space instead of a dash in the `--edit-key` argument, so, gpg is reading that as `--key-edit key` and found 'Test_**key**1024' as a close match to 'key'.

Comment: **Good catch**
**Problem solved**
Thank you.
I tried without the dash and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Because it thinks you want to edit a key named 'key' and the email address on the end is extraneous. Try `gpg --edit-key vivarto@gmail.com` (note the dash between edit and key.